# Restoring output to the terminal after having issued "exec &>filename"

Tags: io-redirection

I am trying to execute the following:

```
exec &>filename
```

After this I am not able to see anything including what I typed, alright.

I frantically try , `exec 1>&1` and `exec 2>&2` , but nothing happens.

Now , without killing the shell , how do I get back the output redirected to the stdout and error redirected to stderr respectively?
Are the file descriptors the only way to refer standard [in|out]put and stderr?

Comment: Hmm... why do you redirect the stderr/stdout of your interactive shell then? This `exec` construct is usually used in scripts that run in a subshell, to redirect their output e.g. to a file. I don't see a use for it in an interactive session.

Comment: @MartinvonWittich I agree with the statement on exec. I agree. I am just a kid playing around :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After you run `exec &>filename`, the standard output and standard error of the shell go to `filename`. Standard input is file descriptor 0 by definition, and standard output is fd 1 and standard error is fd 2.

A file descriptor isn't either redirected or non-redirected: it always go somewhere (assuming that the process has this descriptor open). To redirect a file descriptor means to change where it goes. When you ran `exec &>filename`, stdout and stderr were formerly connected to the terminal, and became connected to `filename`.

There is always a way to refer to the current terminal: [`/dev/tty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap10.html#tag_10_01). When a process opens this file, it always means the process's [controlling terminal](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_114), whichever it is. So if you want to get back that shell's original stdout and stderr, you can do it because the file they were connected to is still around.

```
exec &>/dev/tty
```

Comment: as @Joseph R. answered $(tty) shows me /dev/pty0 , but your command too works, which one is more portable across Unix flavors? thank yo u for the more clear answer.

Comment: @user917279 They're equally portable in the sense of working on different unix flavors. `/dev/tty` works in cases where `$(tty)` doesn't: `/dev/tty` works as long as the process has a controlling terminal (which is the best you can hope, as there has to be something still connecting the process with the terminal), whereas `$(tty)` requires that the terminal still be opened on standard input.

Comment: Why `exec &>/dev/tty` and not `exec >/dev/tty`?

Comment: @AnthonyRutledge Because the question is what to do after `exec &>filename`, not what to do after `exec >filename`.

Answer (score 13):

You want

```
exec &>$(tty)
```

What you're doing in your question is replicating in stdout and stderr the original stdout and stderr which have already been redirected to the file.

As Gilles' answer explains, `tty` will return the terminal device of the current terminal. This is where the three standard file descriptors are coming from/going to by default in a login shell. So the above statement makes use of `tty` to redirect stdout and stderr back to the terminal device as they were before.

If you're concerned about portability (as per your comment on Gilles' answer), both methods (the [tty utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/utilities/tty.html) and the [`/dev/tty` file](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap10.html)) are in the POSIX standard.

**Copied verbatim from Gilles' comment:**

```
There's an advantage to /dev/tty: it works even after exec <somefile, 
whereas $(tty) would complain “not a tty”
```

Comment: it works! Thank you. echo $(tty) gives /dev/pty0 ( in cygwin) ,how is it related to stdin,stdout and what happens with the above statement? please do let me know if I need to ask this as a seperate question.

Comment: @user917279 Answer updated.

Comment: Thank you Joseph. I posted this question before looking at Giles' answer. Thank you very much. Please allow me to mark Giles answer as accepted, for it made even dumb minds like mine to understand properly.

Comment: There's an advantage to `/dev/tty`: it works even after `exec <somefile`, whereas `$(tty)` would complain “not a tty”.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the characteristically enlightening comment :)